# Remove all characters from string which are not on whitelist

Tags: java, regex, replace, character, whitelist

I am trying to write java code which would remove all unwanted characters and let there be only whitelisted ones.

Example:

```
String[] whitelist = {"a", "b", "c"..."z", "0"..."9", "[", "]",...}
```

I want there only letters (lower and uppercase) and numbers + some next characters I would add.
Then I would start `for()` cycle for every character in the string, and replace it with empty string if it isn't on whitelist.

But that isn't good solution. Maybe it could be done somehow using pattern (regex)? Thanks.

Comment: `Maybe it could be done somehow using pattern (regex)?`  Yep, you're right. You can start [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)

Comment: What kind of characters are allowed? Depending on the requirement, the regex might be vastly different.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) which takes a regex:

```
String input = "BAD good {} []";
String output = input.replaceAll("[^a-z0-9\\[\\]]", "");
System.out.println(output); // good[]
```

Or in [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) you could use a [`CharMatcher`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html):

```
CharMatcher matcher = CharMatcher.inRange('a', 'z')
                          .or(CharMatcher.inRange('0', '9'))
                          .or(CharMatcher.anyOf("[]"));
String input = "BAD good {} []";
String output = matcher.retainFrom(input);
```

That just shows the lower case version, making it easier to demonstrate. To include upper case letters, use `"[^A-Za-z0-9\\[\\]]"` in the regex (and any other symbols you want) - and for the `CharMatcher` you can `or` it with `CharMatcher.inRange('A', 'Z')`.

Comment: In the first code, using regex, how would I add next characters to whitelist (not only [ and ], but also space and next chars)?

Comment: Since PerwinCZ is looking for lower and upper case letters, should it be `[^A-Za-z0-9\\[\\]]`?

Comment: @jonhopkins: I was just going on what was in the code - will edit to clarify that.

Comment: OK I fixed it by myself. When I want to add next character, I add to regex before closing ] this: `\\char`.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not too good at regex's, so I wasn't sure if `a-z` covered all letters or not, so it was a question for OP as well as myself :D

Comment: @PerwinCZ: You don't need to escape all characters - only the ones which have a special meaning within regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You could try and match everything that is not in your whitelist and replace it with an empty string:

```
String in = "asng $%& 123";
//this assumes your whitelist contains word characters and whitespaces, adapt as needed
System.out.println(in.replaceAll( "[^\\w\\s]+", "" ));
```