# Find and Replace characters in a string

Tags: java, regex

I am a newbie to Java and looking for an optimized code to find certain characters and replace them with another character.

The possible strings that i could get are,

```
ABC-2233JDK_KD&ERF
PQR-422KF@FG_344GG
XYZ-99848^KDF_FDFG
```

The allowed characters in the string are alphanumerics and "-" and "_"

Anything other than these needs to be replaced with "-"

So for example, the 1st string from above will become,

```
ABC-2233JDK_KD-ERF
```

I have came up with a RegEx to find strings with characters other than the ones allowed.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\$
```

Is there an easy way to replace invalid characters in a string in Java?

Here invalid characters are anything other than, alphanumerics, dashes ("-") and underscores ("_").

Comment: The question was already answered here. Have a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15249047/remove-all-characters-from-string-which-are-not-on-whitelist

Comment: You've placed the `^` outside of character class, and the trailing `\$` should be removed. Otherwise, your regex is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use:

```
String repl = input.replaceAll("[^\\w-]+", "");
```

`^` negates the whole character class and `\w` includes `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and we are adding hyphen in the mix here as per your requirements.